# How can this function be an overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator, data-conversion

this is a program to convert an object having a string containing a date and another object having 3 ints: date, month and year.

```
class date
{
private:
char dt[9];

public: 
//constructors and functions....
};

class dmy
{
private: 
int day,mth,yr;

public:
//constructors..

  operator date()   // This is what my question is about
  {
   char temp[3],str[9]
   itoa(day,str,10)
   strcat(str,"/");
  itoa(mth,temp,10);
  strcat(str,temp)
  strcat(str,"/");
  itoa(yr,temp,10);
  strcat(str,temp);

  return (date(str));
  }

};

int main
{
 date d1;
 dmy d2(17,11,94);

 d1=d2;

 //display d1's and d2's data
 return 0; 
}
```

My confusion lies in the operator date() part. how can date be an operator? shouldn't the = operator be overloaded to carry out this conversion?

Comment: Sometimes you can't overload the assignment operator or add a constructor, e.g. if the `date` type belongs to a library that you can't modify, or you just want to avoid introducing that dependency.

Answer (score 1):

A function of this form of

```
operator T() { /*return an object of type T*/ }
```

is called user-defined conversion function, which is invoked implicitly when an object of type `T` is required in any expression.

In your case, the user-defined conversion function is defined to implicity convert an object of type `dmy` into an object of type `date`.

```
void f(date dt);

dmy dmyObj; 

date dateObj = dmyObj; //ok. conversion function is invoked implicitly
f(dmyObj); //ok. conversion function is invoked implicitly
```

Answer (score 0):

```
operator date()
```

Is a **[conversion function](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/lnxpcomp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8l.doc/language/ref/cplr385.htm)**, wherever in your code a `date` type is needed and instead a `dmy` type is being used then this operator will be called implicitly to create an `date` type and use it.